# Find all distinct left cosets of the subgroup $7\mathbb{Z}$ in the group $\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

Find all distinct left cosets of the subgroup $H$ in the group $G$,where $ H = 7\mathbb{Z}$, $G = \mathbb{Z}$.

This was a question given in a book.  My solution goes like this:

> We know that two left cosets of a subgroup is either distinct or equal. However, in this subgroup the elements are of the of the form $7x$ , where $x\in\mathbb {Z}$. Now, if we add $b\in\mathbb {Z}$ , then we get a coset $bH=b+7x$. But $b+7x\in\mathbb {Z}$. Now, we know that every integer can be expressed as $7k,7k+1,7k+2,...,7k+6$ . Hence, every arbitary coset $bH$, where $b\in\mathbb{Z}$ has elements of the form $b+7x=7x+b$. Also, $7x+b\equiv r\pmod{7}$ iff $b\equiv r\pmod{7}$ and $r\in\{0,1,...,6\}$. Now, if $c\in \mathbb {Z}$, and $7x+c\equiv r\pmod{7}$ , we claim that $7x+c\in bH$. This is because $b\equiv c\pmod{7}$ and hence $c=b+7k_1$. Thus, $7k+c=7(k+k_1)+b\in bH$ . So, we can say it has $7$ distinct cosets.

Is the above solution correct? Is it valid? If not,  where is it going wrong?

Comment: $bH\neq b+7x; bH=\{b+7x:x\in \Bbb Z\}$

Comment: It is essentially correct but I found it hard to decipher because too verbous.

Comment: We should denote $b+H$ instead of $bH$, and even simply $b+7\Bbb Z$: $G$ is the group $(\Bbb Z,+)$, not to be confused with the underlying set $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: There are often two ways of approaching a question. First is a guess free way, in which you do not guess what the answer is and proceed so that the answer reveals itself. The second is the guess dependent way, in which you already know what the answer is and you prove that your guess is true. Here the 2nd way is more useful. You directly guess that $\{\Bbb{7Z,1+7Z,...,6+7Z}\}$ is the list of all cosets and then you pick any integer, express it as $7k+r\,,0\leq r<7$ using division algorithm and then place it in the appropirate coset and hence argue that you exhaust all possibilities.